# write Arabic in Actionscript 3.0 with air for Android

Tags: android, arabic

I make an application for the Android operating system using the program Adobe flash and language Actionscript 3.0, but I have a problem in adding a text box type Editable, it does not support Arabic language. 
I hope that you will find a solution to my problem. 
Thank you